# Redux middleware getting access to store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Using Redux I am implementing an external package which exposes the following middleware, as the second parameter it expects a `function` which returns a `Promise`

```
const token = () => {
  // I want to get some data which is already in the store here.
  return fetch('endpoint')
  .then((response) => response.text())
}

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  middleware({Some: 'Object'}, token)
)(createStore)
```

My issue is I need to grab data which is already in the `state`, in this case an auth token. Does anyone have a good idea how I can grab the `state`? I know inside a middleware function I have access to the `store` but I don't control this external package so I am stuck with this method signature.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the external middleware in your own middleware. Your own middleware gives the store to your `token` function.

Assuming that the `middleware` function returns a function that respects the signature as from [redux doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html#arguments):

```
const token = store => () => {
  // here you can use the store to get the info from the state
  return fetch('endpoint')
  .then((response) => response.text())
}

const myMiddlewareWithToken = store => next => action => {
  middleware({ Some: 'Object' }, token(store))(store)(next)(action);
}

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  myMiddleware
)(createStore);
```